# JavaScript Save DropDown filter data on Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, user-interface

I have requirement to save drop down filter date on click on save button and page refresh.

I have achieved on save button filter.

Now I want save drop on page refresh which will happens on every minute.

I am try to call this function timeout funtion, but I could able save filter data on refresh now idea how to achieve this.

```js
// ============= This is the function which will filter ==========================
function getSubrackOpticalChassis(sub) {
  var data = {};

  forceRefresh();
  data.wcsNum_op = {{Can}};
  data.page = 'OpticalLinkPerformance';
  data.subrack = sub;

  formCreation("systemOperation_form", "/cgi-bin/sysOperation.cgi", data);
  $('#systemOperation_form').submit();
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    getOpticalLinkPerformance();
    getSubrackOpticalChassis(sub);
  }, 60000);
})
```

```html
<button id="save-" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 0px !important;" tabindex="0" 
onclick="getSubrackOpticalChassis ($('#chooseSubrack_form option:selected').val())">Save</button>
```

Comment: I had a hard time formatting your code into something readable. Please take care how you edit.

Comment: `$('#chooseSubrack_form option:selected').val()` is the same as `$('#chooseSubrack_form').val()` if chooseSubrack_form is the select

Comment: There is not enough information in your code. Please click edit and then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] WITHOUT any templating, just HTML, CSS if needed and JS

Comment: Why do you reload the page when you can use AJAX instead?

Comment: If you want to save data between page reloads, you could use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).